# Verifying a radio input has been checked to display div on separate page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an issue of hiding and displaying content on a separate page if a certain radio input has been checked. Currently I am trying to hide special content if the user hasn't checked one radio input. I have code that works for that page which switches the banner to allow them to go to the page after they complete this task, but when I go to the next page the content doesnt show up.

Here is my current script for the banner to hide and show based on the radio input being checked.

```
if ($('input[name=sexo-field]:checked').length > 0) {
    $("#pdfFlipButton").show();
    $("#pdfFlipButtonOff").hide();
} else {
    $("#pdfFlipButton").hide();
    $("#pdfFlipButtonOff").show();
}
```

But how would I go about showing or hiding a div on the next page based on these parameters?

Comment: Stick the radio button in a form, submit the form, catch the values on the next page.

Comment: You can also use sessionStorage, but the way @adeneo says is easier.

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy and you have 3 not good ways:

1. The page that must be affected, is a child page and send data from parent page to child page.
2. In both page create ajax functions, send direction from one and another must check the server in a few seconds:

   ```
   setInterval(function(){ 
      //if radio checked
   }, 3000);
   ```
3. As mentioned in comments, submit radio button and refresh second page.

Answer (score 0):

As @adeneo said, you can wrap the radio button in the form element and after submitting that form, catch values on the next page which the form points on. Or as @Michael Alexander Montero said, you can use sessionStorage which I would rather recommend.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) is the documentation of how to use sessionStorage. In your case it would be for example:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('radiochecked', true);
```

And in the next page you will add following line:

```
if(sessionStorage.getItem('radiochecked') {
     // display the panel
}
```

Comment: That would work perfect, but this is a pre-built form through a wordpress plugin called profile builder. How would I get access to that radio or is there a way to call it in javascript to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: If you can find the radio button, you can add jquery's $(element).on() event listener. For example: `$('input[name=sexo-field]').on('change', function() { if($('input[name=sexo-field]:checked')) {sessionStorage.setItem('radiochecked', true);}})`